# How can I change the background color in table header and fix the header in HTML, without JavaScript?

Tags: html, css

I tried to use this, but it didn't work.

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If the following is the layout of your basic table:

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Something Here</th></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

then here is what you can do:

```
th{
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

where `th` is the table-header.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp) is a reference link on the table headers. I hope it will be helpful.

This is the working example:

```css
th {
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Something Here</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could say in your css, that the first `<tr>` (in which the `<th>` tags usually are) has a specific background and should be fixed

```
tr:first-child
{
  background-color: yourColor;
  position:fixed;
}
```

This example might also help you out https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu